# How to run Node.js jobs routines

Tags: node.js, jobs

Right now I have a weekly email job that works by first checking a last_email_sent timestamp against the current time, it then uses setTimeout to schedule a routine that is exactly a week from the last_email_sent timestamp. If the process ever restarts, the setTimeout would be queued again but the interval would of course be smaller. This works for a weekly email job, but is there a better way to handle jobs in node.js? Maybe there's a module out there that can let me manage my jobs that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a handy module in npmjs.org called [node-cron](https://npmjs.org/package/cron).

It'll give you more flexibility.

Comment: What would happen if the process that uses this module crashes; would the scheduled cron job still run?

Answer (score 1):

Many of the [modules listed in the node.js wiki under "Message Queues"](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Modules#wiki-message-queue) will help with this type of system. Being a TJ Holowaychuck fanboy, I myself would probably first look at [Kue](https://github.com/learnboost/kue).

Comment: Is there a way to queue a job for a specific day of the week using Kue?

Comment: Do you think that comment deserves an answer?

Comment: The README only mentioned that you could delay a job using a number of milliseconds; I recall it never said anything about specifying a day of the week, much like how you could with a cron job. Please don't be rude. :)

Comment: Also, I mean have the job queued for a specific day _every_ week, a repeating job.

Comment: why do you feel like that comment doesn't deserve an answer? How would I be able to determine the number of milliseconds from now, say Thursday, is?